# MATLAB mapping toolbox - how to plot lat/lon coordinates onto a created map?

Tags: plot, maps, latitude-longitude, matlab

I have this map of California I generated with the following code:

```
states = geoshape(shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true));
figure
ax = usamap('california');
oceanColor = [.5 .7 .9];
setm(ax, 'FFaceColor', oceanColor)
geoshow(states)
title({ 'California map'})
```

Now I want to plot specific points on the map using latitude and longitude coordinates. I can't "guesstimate" because I have to plot 100 or so points. How do I do that? I look everywhere and couldn't find a syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`plotm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/plotm.html) or [`linem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/linem.html), the equivalent of MATLAB's [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) functions respectively (they accept the same "line style specifications").

Here is an example:

```
% California map axes
figure; ax = usamap('california');
setm(ax, 'FFaceColor', [.5 .7 .9])
title('California map')

% read shapefile of US states with names and locations
states = geoshape(shaperead('usastatehi.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true));

% display map
geoshow(states, 'Parent',ax)

% find states within the shown axes limits (California and Nevada)
latlim = getm(ax, 'MapLatLimit');
lonlim = getm(ax, 'MapLonLimit');
idx = ingeoquad(states.LabelLat, states.LabelLon, latlim, lonlim);

% latitude/longitude coordinates and corresponding labels
lat = states(idx).LabelLat;
lon = states(idx).LabelLon;
txt = states(idx).Name;

% plot coordinates
%plot(lat, lon, 'rx')
linem(lat, lon, 'LineStyle','none', 'LineWidth',2, 'Color','r', ...
    'Marker','x', 'MarkerSize',10)
textm(lat, lon, txt, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'left', 'VerticalAlignment','top')
```

[image: plot_lon_lat_coordinates]